# parametric fractal dimension code in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, dimension, fractals

I am beginner in Mathematica. I write code in mathematica for finding parametric fractal dimension. But it doesn't work. Can someone explain me where I am wrong.
My code is:

```
delta[0] = 0.001
lambda[0] = 0
div = 0.0009
a = 2
b = 2
terms = 100
fx[0] = NSum[1/n^b, {n, 1, terms}]
fy[0] = 0
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++,
 delta[i] = delta[i - 1] + div;
 j = 0
    While[lambda[j] <= Pi,
     j = j + 1;
     lambda[j] = lambda[j - 1] + delta[i];
     fx[j] = NSum[Cos[n^a*lambda[j]]/n^b, {n, 1, terms}]; 
     fy[j] = NSum[Sin[n^a*lambda[j]]/n^b, {n, 1, terms}];
     deltaL[j] = Sqrt[[fx[j] - fx[j - 1]]^2 + [fy[j] - fy[j - 1]]^2];
     ]
    Ldelta[i] = Sum[deltaL[j], {j, 1, 10}];
 ]
data = Table[{Log[delta[i]], Log[Ldelta[i]]}, {i, 1, 10}]
line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
ListPlot[data]
```

Comment: In two places you are incorrectly using [...]^2 instead of (...)^2. Mathematica is fanatic about correct use of () versus [] versus {}. You will probably also have fewer obscure problems in the future if you end each statement with a semicolon. If you do not then at odd times Mathematica will think you have one statement multiplying two items rather than having two separate statements.